# How to bash complete an alias as the command

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, tab-completion

I have an alias

```
alias gi=git
```

Unlike `git`, `gi` cannot complete on subcommands, paths, branches.

How can I tell bash to "complete X as if it were Y"?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/436314/how-can-i-get-bash-to-perform-tab-completion-for-my-aliases ?

Comment: The answer here is better than the ones at https://superuser.com/questions/436314/how-can-i-get-bash-to-perform-tab-completion-for-my-aliases . I'm going to add it there as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably want to add this to your *.bashrc* or *.bash_aliases*.

```
# load git completions
_completion_loader git

# assign git's completion function _git to gi
complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F _git gi
```

Alternatively you can use the following (which is pretty much equivalent):

```
# load git completions
. /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git

# assign git's completion function _git to gi
__git_complete gi _git
```

Note, you can skip the first line (of either of the aforementioned examples) if dynamic completions are **not** enabled. You should probably assume it is enabled though.